# jQuery not working the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, padding

I am having a problem with my website.
The padding-top of div class="row slide-content" is acting weird.
For some slides it is about 223px and for other slides it uses a different padding.

PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="home-slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php while ($slide =& $loop->next()): ?>

            <li>
                <div class="row slide-content">
                    <div class="large-10 large-centered columns text-center">
                        <?php if ( ! empty( $slide->button ) ) : ?>

                        <div class="SLIDERLOGO">
                            <?php echo $slide->button; ?>
                        </div><?php endif; ?><?php if ( ! empty( $slide->ititle ) || ! empty( $slide->caption ) ) : ?>

                        <div class="hero-title">
                            <div class="large-3 columns nopad border-bottom">
                            </div>

                            <div class="large-6 columns text-center">
                                <?php if ( ! empty( $slide->ititle ) ) : ?>

                                <h4 class="text-white alt-h">
                                <?php echo $slide->ititle; ?></h4><?php endif; ?>
                            </div><?php if ( empty( $slide->ititle ) ) : ?>

                            <div class="large-6 columns nopad border-bottom">
                            </div><?php endif; ?>

                            <div class="large-3 columns nopad border-bottom">
                            </div>

                            <h1 class="text-white">
                            <?php echo $slide->caption; ?></h1>
                        </div><!--end of hero title-->
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div><img alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $slide->alt ); ?>" class=
                "slider-bg" src=
                "%3C?php%20echo%20esc_attr(%20$slide-%3Eimg%20);%20?%3E">
            </li><?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div><!--end of Home slider-->
</body>
</html>
```

The logo is inserted here

```
<?php echo $slide->button; ?>
```

Both logo's are exactly the same dimensions

JS
// Append HTML 's as CSS Background for slides
    // also center the content of the slide

```
jQuery('.home-slider .slides li').each(function () {

    var imgSrc = jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').attr('src');
    jQuery(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
    jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').remove();

    var slideHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    var contentHeight = jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').height();
    var padTop = (slideHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2);

    jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').css('padding-top', padTop);

});
```

It wont happen every time but sometimes the padding between the logo and the top of the page changes. I hope i have explained wel enough :)

Many thanks!
Daan

Comment: It looks like you are calculating `padTop` so if the result is not the same every time, then that means `(slideHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)` is returning different values (slideHeight or contentHeight is not the same for each slide). You should shorten up the html code and use generated source

Answer (score 0):

try running your code on $(window).load(function() { }); instead of at the bottom of the page, chances are if you are working with larger slide images that not all of them are fully loaded before your calculations are applying.

The new code would look like this...

```
jQuery(window.load(function() {
jQuery('.home-slider .slides li').each(function () {

    var imgSrc = jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').attr('src');
    jQuery(this).css('background', 'url("' + imgSrc + '")');
    jQuery(this).children('.slider-bg').remove();

    var slideHeight = jQuery(this).height();
    var contentHeight = jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').height();
    var padTop = (slideHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2);

    jQuery(this).children('.slide-content').css('padding-top', padTop);

});
});
```